# Are Night Vision Goggles in DayZ Standalone yet?

Tags: dayz-standalone

Are night vision goggles in the DayZ Standalone game?

I am trying to figure out how careful I need to be at night - if everyone is on the same level of vision unless they use a flashlight, I'd be less worried than if there's a chance there is someone out there with NV goggles who can see me clearly.

I searched the forums and couldn't find any comments addressing these in particular.

Comment: Hey, @bobfet1.  I removed the timestamp, because questions should be able to withstand the test of time.  Any answers you get can be updated, in the event they are currently not in the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not in the game yet, but if you are in the dark and you turn your video gamma all the way up and your brightness it will look like night vision. So be warned, some people do this, and won't use the flash light or lantern

Here is the normal setting: 
[image: Normal settings]

And this is the gamma and brightness turned up:
[image: Brightness and gamma turned up]

Comment: When I get home tonight ill take a screenshot in the night with it on normal, and with it turned all the way up.

Comment: Also be aware this is dependent on the moon. A night with no moon will still be pitch black regardless of gamma and brightness. I play almost exclusively on night servers with a full moon.